# Eager Loading with where

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

I want to list all the garages by the car id, but the way I'm doing still returning informations about garages even if the car isn't found, the opposite happen, instead of nothing return, the garages returns with the car relations as empty.

Let me put in an example:

```
$garages = Garages::with(['cars'])->get();
```

This way I have everything, and I can't use `->where('car_id', 1)` because the table `garage` doesn't have the `car_id` column. The only way I found was like this:

```
$garages = Garages::with(['cars' => function($q) { return $q->where('car_id', 1); }])->get();
```

The problem is that even if the car isn't found still returning data from garage and I don't want that because I want to use `@forelse` in blade and as it still returning data the `@empty` never works, and I get errors saying that I'm trying to get properties from a non-object (of course, cars doesn't exist if wasn't found).

Is there a way to use `where` and return data only if it was found?

@edit - The relations

```
class Users extends Eloquent
{
    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('cars');
    }

    public function garages()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('garages', 'cars', 'garage_id', 'garage_id');
    }
}

class Garages extends Eloquent
{
    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('cars');
    }
}

class Cars extends Eloquent
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('users');
    }

    public function garages()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Garages');
    }       
}
```

Comment: Set up the `Cars` relationship properly and this will be handled by Laravel.

Comment: I edited and now you can see the relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going all wrong about this. If you need the garages of one car why not find the car and get all the garages using the relationship?

```
$user = User::find(1);
$garages = $user->garages;

foreach($garages as $garage){
    // just an example, you'll have to use your real properties
    echo 'Address: ' . $garage->address;
    echo 'Name: '. $user->name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.

```
$garages = Garages::with(['cars' => function($q) { $q->where('car_id', 1); }])
                    ->whereHas('cars', function($q) { $q->where('car_id', 1); })
                    ->get();
```

**Update:**
I have found another way to do this..

```
$garages = Garages::has('cars')
                    ->with(['cars'])
                    ->get();
```

Comment: No you could not put condition on nest relationships, In Eager Loading data load according to the Modal's relationships. Here you have one to many relationship so it will return you a collection. So you could not put condition on a collection.

Comment: Then how can I make a `where` and retrieve the informations between `hasManyThrough` relationship? - The answer above you can see the relationships.

Comment: Read this, please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511020/eager-loading-with-where/27511295?noredirect=1#comment43455817_27511295